# Solving cyclical dependency for friend classes

Tags: c++

On the most basic level, I need a method from a class to access private data from another class, such as:

foo.h:

```
class foo{
    void method( void );
}
```

bar.h:

```
class bar{
   friend void foo::method( void );
}
```

However, method needs to know which object to be accessing, making it look more like this:

foo.h:

```
class foo{
    void method(bar* point);
}
```

bar.h:

```
class bar{
    friend void foo::method(bar* point);
}
```

However, as you can see this gives cyclical dependency: bar would need foo.h for declaring a friend, and foo would need bar.h as it uses a bar pointer. How else would the method know which object to access?

Comment: You can forward declare the class above the other.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Why not post an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find yourself in a cyclic dependency, **it is probably best to review your design** once. Once you review the design and *if you still feel* the need for the cyclic dependency, You need to use a **Forward declaration** of the class.

```
class bar;
class foo
{
    void method(bar* point);
}
```

**Good Read:**
[When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)

Comment: I've done this - they are stored in separate header files, which seems to be the problem - The first won't compile without the other, and so on and so fourth

Comment: Really, nothing to add? I need an answer to get this working!

Comment: @Joe Have you tried adding forward declarations for each class to both files?

Comment: @0x499602D2, Yes I have. To no avail. the first won't compile because it can't include the second, because it can't compile because the first can't be included because it has not yet been compiled...